# Inside Ajax code ,success is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I m using express,node.js and mysql.Inside Ajax code ,success is not working.Below is the ajax code.

```
function GetData_1(){
 var  state = $("#dpState_1").val();
 console.log(state);
 $.ajax({
 url:"http://localhost:5000/postDistrict",
     type: "post",
     data: {objectData :state},
     dataType: "json",           
     crossDomain: "true",      
     success: function (result) {
     console.log('Im reaching at the postDistrict');
     $.ajax({
           url:"http://localhost:5000/getDistrict",
           type: "get",
           dataType: "json",           
           crossDomain: "true",      
           success: function (result) {
             console.log("Inside Success")
             $.each(result,function(index,obj){
             $("#dpDistrict_1").append("<option value = " + obj.dist + ">" + obj.dist+              
              "</option>"); });   
             },
             error: function (obj, txtStatus, error) {
          alert("There was some error,could not fetch data.....");
              }
             });
            },
          error: function (obj, txtStatus, error) {
          alert("There was some error,could not fetch data... :((");
          }
        });
       }
```

But data(i.e state) is getting posted at the required URL.And further with the help of the node.js, i m fetching the post content using POST,then using GET to place the data in HTML  and the code of is below:

```
 var application_root = __dirname,
     express = require("express"),
     mysql = require('mysql2');
     path = require("path");

 var app = express();

 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '123',
    database: "info"
 });

 app.use(express.bodyParser());
 app.use(express.cookieParser('shhhh, very secret'));
 app.use(express.session());

 // Config

 app.configure(function () {
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
 app.use(express.methodOverride());
 app.use(app.router);
 app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "public")));
 app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
 });

 app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
   next();
 });



  app.post('/postDistrict', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body.objectData);
      var state = req.body.objectData;
      app.get('/getDistrict', function(request, response){
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          console.log('select dist from information where  state =' +"'"+ state + "'");
          connection.query('select dist from information where  state =' +"'"+ state + 
          "'", function(err, rows) {
          response.json(rows);
          });
      });
  });

  // Launch server
  app.listen(5000, function(){
  console.log('Server running...');
  });
```

Comment: If success is not firing, then it means your server does't return state 200 after processing request.

Comment: @setec..i m just new to node.js,so can u just tell me what updation i have to do in the code so that it will work...

Comment: Im wondering if you use a crossDomain-Call there, because you set the required flags and headers in your code. To help you debug, you should run `curl -I http://localhost:5000/getDistrict` to get more information about the Status-Code (state 200).

BTW: Did you include a GET_Route for the getDistrict? Because I can't find it in the code.

If you don't know how to use curl, try one of the dozens 'http header viewer' services online.

Answer (score 0):

try to use in your ajax async: false

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"ajax/cart.php",
        async:false,
        data:"prod_id="+$('#prodh_id').val()+"&qty="+$('#qty').val()+"",
        success: function(result)
```